# Promise in loop, code after loop is not executed

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using a loop to query events, but the code after the loop is not executed. Why is this the case and how do I solve this problem?

```
router.post("/components/Pages/BrokerAPage/queryAll", (req, res) => {
  var requestedResult;

  for (i = 0; i < EventIDList.length; i++) {
      queryEvent(EventIDList[i])
          .then((result) => {
              if (result) {
                  requestedResult += result;
              }
          })
          .catch(err =>
              res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: err.message})));
    }
    console.log("*************TEST************")
    console.log("*************"+requestedResult+"*************")
    res.json(JSON.stringify(requestedResult));
});
```

Comment: but `queryEvent` is fired multiple times?

Comment: It should be executed but requestedResult is empty

Comment: This is an async issue. You have to wait until all calls to queryEvent are finished. Otherwise you might get to your last three lines of code before requestedResult holds the expected output.

Comment: Your for loop is not synchronous. After promise is return, print `requestedResult`.

Comment: @mr.void: why is it empty? it's not empty within the loop...

Comment: `but the code after the loop is not executed. ` @Shubham for me this means that also the `*******TEST*******` is not printed and this has nothing to do with async behaviour

Comment: Its empty cause promises are resolve async. When requestedResult is outputted the queryEvent promises are not done. You should store queryEvent in array an use Promise.all()

Comment: Promises are also asynchronous. The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value. And the code after the loop will execute but not with updated values. For asynchronous calls, it's better to use recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.post("/components/Pages/BrokerAPage/queryAll", (req, res) => {
    var requestedResult;
    var promises = [];
    EventIDList.forEach((EventID) => {
        // gather all Promises
        promises.push(queryEvent(EventID)
            .then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    requestedResult += result;
                }
            }));
    });
    // wait till all promises are settled, then log result 
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        console.log("*************TEST************");
        console.log("*************" + requestedResult + "*************");
        res.json(JSON.stringify(requestedResult));
    }).catch(err => res.send(JSON.stringify({
        status: "error",
        message: err.message
    })));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) npm module to make the loop synchronous.

```
router.post("/components/Pages/BrokerAPage/queryAll", (req, res) => {
  var requestedResult;
async.eachOf(EventIDList, function(EventId, index, acb) {
queryEvent(EventId)
          .then((result) => {
              if (result) {
                  requestedResult += result;
                  return acb(null);
              }
          })
          .catch(err =>
              res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'error', message: err.message})));
           return acb(null);
    }
});
```